# Why doesn't Djinn find <*> for State?

Tags: haskell, theorem-proving

I define

```hs
-- Djinn doesn't seem to understand newtype
data State s a = State (s -> (s, a))
```

and then ask it for

```hs
f :: State s (a -> b) -> State s a -> State s b
```

It gives me three answers, but *all* of them throw away one or both of the state changes. Why is this? Isn't Djinn supposed to prefer solutions that use as much of the available information as possible? There are two *linear* solutions here, and yet neither shows up.

Comment: @DanielWagner: I guess the minimal requirement would be the *ordered* linear one. If you phrase it in combinator calculus, one of them needs an extra “swap” combinator `Ckxy=kyx`, while the other doesn’t (and can be interpreted in any monoidal category, I think?)